# (Python) How to use both selenium and requests to print out a microsoft page

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests, web-crawler

So basically I'm trying to log in to microsoft on this page: https://login.live.com/

[image]

using selenium, because requests is for more basic authentication pages. here is my selenium code

```
email = 'password'
password = 'password'

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


EMAILFIELD = (By.ID, "i0116")
PASSWORDFIELD = (By.ID, "i0118")
NEXTBUTTON = (By.ID, "idSIButton9")

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://login.live.com')

WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(EMAILFIELD)).send_keys(email)

WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(NEXTBUTTON)).click()

WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(PASSWORDFIELD)).send_keys(password)

WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(NEXTBUTTON)).click()

WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(NEXTBUTTON)).click()
```

and then I want to use requests to print out the page after I aunthenticate. Here is my requests code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
    
req = requests.get("https://account.microsoft.com/?lang=en-US&refd=account.live.com&refp=landing&mkt=EN-US")

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.title)
print(req)
```

the expected outcome is the html title of this page: https://account.microsoft.com/?lang=en-US&refd=account.live.com&refp=landing&mkt=EN-US (Microsoft account | Home)

```
<title>Microsoft account | Home</title>
<Response [200]>
```

[image]

but instead the output i am getting is

```
<title>Microsoft account | Sign In or Create Your Account Today – Microsoft</title>
<Response [200]>
```

which is this page: https://account.microsoft.com/account (Microsoft account | Sign In or Create Your Account Today – Microsoft)

[image]

Please help me, and thank you in advance!

Comment: what `req` is returning can you please share status code of that

Comment: <Response [200]>

Comment: Did you try using selenium to print the title ? I see you have a different end point in case of request module

Comment: No, but I was wondering if I could use request. It's easier for me. if need be though, i will use selenium all the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are login via selenium and **scraping** through bs, which are independent of each other, so whenever you do

`"https://account.microsoft.com/"`

via requests you need to log in via API(if there's any), or in simple words they both are different session

JYFI, if you do

`browser.get("https://account.microsoft.com/")`

and then print the title, it will work, but it won't work with the current approach